# Vue 3 - cannot bind any attribute

Tags: vue.js, binding, attributes, vuejs3, bind

can you help me with binding attributes with Vue 3?

I have app created which works well as it is, but when I put it into XML `<content type="html>" VUE APP </content>` the bindings doesn't work.

Issue is that as text it shows up, but in bindings it shows as object name.

ex.

```
{{someValueFromVueObject.url}}
{{someValueFromVueObject.height}}
<iframe :src="someValueFromVueObject.url" :height="someValueFromVueObject.height"></iframe>
<iframe v-bind:src="someValueFromVueObject.url" v-bind:height="someValueFromVueObject.height"></iframe>
```

that output code is like this (not binding values)

```
https:\\google.com\ 
800
<iframe src="someValueFromVueObject.url" height="someValueFromVueObject.height"></iframe>
<iframe src="someValueFromVueObject.url" height="someValueFromVueObject.height"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what issue you are facing but It's working fine. Here is the demo **:**

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data: () => ({
    someValueFromVueObject: {
      url: 'https:\\google.com',
      height: 100
    }
  })
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{someValueFromVueObject.url}}
  {{someValueFromVueObject.height}}<br>
  <iframe :src="someValueFromVueObject.url" :height="someValueFromVueObject.height"></iframe>
</div>
```

Please check this code snippet and let me know what challenge you are facing.

Comment: As I told, it works well when it is separately, but the isue is when the app is rendered by XML <content type="html">

Comment: You updated it just 20 minutes back. Let me check